# debconf hanged on 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade path to Tahr

Tags: debconf

I was notified of a difference in /etc/default/grub, so I clicked "Run a shell to examine the situation". But the debconf windows turned dimmed and no terminal opened. What can I do? I'm stuck there, seeing this in a manually launched terminal:

```
ps ax |grep debconf

23598 pts/1    S      0:02 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst configure 2.00-13ubuntu3

23642 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/ucf --three-way --debconf-ok --sum-file=/usr/share/grub/default/grub.md5sum /tmp/grub.6GKAkQNvBB /etc/default/grub
```

Can I [sudo] kill 23642 or rather 23598 ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a terminal I first killed the 23642 process I beleived as a subprocess, but this didn't help as the dimmed window was still here. Then I used xkill from the terminal over the dimmed window which closed ok, freeing the installation to run up to its end. Before rebooting I went to /etc/default/ and found grub, grub~ (an old backup), grub.me (my fresh backup) and a grub.something.threeway or so. I just had to make all that stuff clean. BTW, I must add more info: I never selected the three way compare. More, in a first step I choose the first option (in my memory) and I noticed the compare option was ***not*** the one I selected. So I suspect there is a bug in the handling code.